# How to get the number of records in a Data Reader?

Tags: c#, record, datareader

I'm trying to display the number of records in the data reader. Here's what I tried.

```
if (mybtnreader1.HasRows)
{
   using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
   {
       dt.Load(mybtnreader1);
       int rc = dt.Rows.Count;
       MessageBox.Show("Have "+rc+"records");
   }
}
```

Though it has records it is always displaying 0. How should it be corrected or is there any other way to get the number of records in a data reader?

I'm using this code to display the data.

```
while(mybtnreader1.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show(mybtnreader1.GetValue(0) + "  "+mybtnreader1.GetValue(1)+" ");
}
```

It is showing the data but when it comes to the number of records it is displaying 0.

Comment: are you sure records are present in datatable?

Comment: can you try displaying the records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looping through the results of your query you can use  [`RecordsAffected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.recordsaffected.aspx):

```
mybtnreader1 = command.ExecuteReader();

 while(mybtnreader1.Read())
        {

          ///do your stuff
        }

mybtnreader1 .Close();
MessageBox.Show(mybtnreader1 .RecordsAffected.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

A DataReader is forward-only read-only so you can't get the number of records before looping through them all. While you loop through you can count, but not before.

If you need to know the number of records ahead of time and want the performance and memory advantages of a DataReader, then change your query to run two queries.. first the same underlying query with a `select count(*)...` and then the actual query. Depending on the query, this will obviously affect performance. It won't be double the time due to caching, but is additional processing time. You'll have to weigh the need for having the count ahead of time vs the advantages of using a DataReader vs a DataTable.

For example, if you're querying every record from a table like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
using(var dataReader = ...)
```

Then you can do this instead:

```
string sql = @"
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable;
                SELECT * FROM MyTable;
             };
using(var dataReader = ...)
{
    ... process first result in data reader (count) ...
    if (dataReader.NextResult) 
    {
       ... process the second result (records) ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is my query, 
      SqlCommand mybtncmd02 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM DirectNodes", mybtnconn1);
can you show me an example of how to add the second query?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it directly with Datareader. you can do it like below -

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt_results = new DataTable();
dt_results.Load(reader);
int count= dt_results.Rows.Count;
if(count>0)
{
    //Hey! we Have records for this query
}
else{
    //Sorry! No Records Exist for this query
}
```